# Jquery Dialog reading textarea value only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I am using a dialog with a textarea. Upon clicking the ok-button the textarea's value gets sent to a server via ajax.
The first time the user writes to the textarea the value gets read correctly, but upon all subsequent actions the value being sent is the same as the first time as if the user had entered the same string over and over again.

```
function message(url) { 
  var mydiv; 
  mydiv = $(document.createElement('div')); 
  mydiv.html("enter message: <textarea name='message' id='message'/>"); 
  mydiv.dialog(setProps(url));
  mydiv.dialog('open');
}

function setProps(url) {
  return {
    buttons: {
      "ok": function() {
        $.get('/act?url=' + url + '&message=' + $("#message").val().trim(),
          function(data) { 
            $("#content").load('/react?url=' + url); 
          }
        ); 
        $(this).dialog("close"); 
        $(this).dialog("destroy"); 
        // If I use the following all subseq. actions are empty:
        // $("#message").val(''); 
      }
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I suspect, the problem is the attempt to add an element with id='message' multiple times(since id's need to be unique). Replacing it with class='message' 'might' solve your problem.

Comment: @conqenator - `.val()` would still get the *first* element's value.

Comment: @Nick: hmmm, using .last().val() would solve that, right?  But, I guess thats not the best way.

Comment: @conqenator - yeah you're really side-stepping the core issue here, **always** solve the problem, not the symptoms.

Comment: @Nick:  Yes, couldn't agree more :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a dialog it gets appending at the end of the `<body>`, just because you're destroying the dialog doesn't mean the elements in it go away, they're just returned to their location, or in this case still at the end of the `<body>`, you also need to [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) those elements, like this:

```
$(this).dialog("destroy").remove();
```

Otherwise (currently) you're adding a *new* `#message` element each time, and what you're seeing is a classic duplicate ID issue, it's getting the value of the first one (the first you appended...that never left).

---

Overall there are a few more issues, for example IE<9 not having `String.prototype.trim()` so your value would blow up, as would having anything like `&` in it.  Let jQuery encode your values, like this:

```
function message(url) { 
 $("<div>enter message: <textarea name='message' id='message'></textarea></div>")
   .dialog(setProps(url));
}

function setProps(url) {
  return {
    buttons: {
      "ok": function() {
        $.get('/act', { url: url, message: $.trim($("#message").val()) },
          function(data) { 
            $("#content").load('/react?url=' + url); 
          }
        ); 
        $(this).dialog("destroy").remove(); 
      }
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Even if I'm a late arrival, thanks very much for the hint! It solved my puzzle after a whole morning spent to debug my javascript code